# Fix alternating row-colours in slickgrid when using jquery-ui themes

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, slickgrid

I have a proposal for improving the row-colours in SlickGrid using jquery-ui themes.

I made some jsfiddles to show the problems with jquery-themes and how they can be resolved. I integrated the **Super Theme-roller Switcher** so you can directly see how the Slick-Grid appears with all the standard themes.

[Standard slickgrid](http://jsfiddle.net/eierfiddle/74bYq/). Here you can see that the theme "Smoothness" looks good but there are problems with themes with a light-coloured active-ui (eg. Black tie), causing the row-alternation to disappear or even worse with strongly coloured themes (e.g. Le Frog) where the text in odd rows becomes unreadable.

[Improved slickgrid](http://jsfiddle.net/eierfiddle/bRF3d/). Here you can see my version which resolves the problems above.

The changes are very simple. In **slick.grid.js**, function `appendRowHtml`,  I appended the standard ui-classes to the even and odd rows.

```
//(row % 2 == 1 ? " odd" : " even");
(row % 2 == 1 ? " ui-state-default odd" : " ui-state-active even");
```

Then in "slick-default-theme.css" I removed the style directives that were interfering with the standard jquery-UI classes.

```
.slick-row.ui-state-active {
  /*background: #F5F7D7;*/
}

.slick-row.odd {
  /*background: #fafafa;*/
}

.slick-row.ui-state-active {
  /*background: #F5F7D7;*/
}
```

Would these changes be the correct way to fix row-colours in SlickGrid?

Comment: Shouldn't you be posting this on the author's issues site on GitHub? https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues? I don't think SO is a place for discussions..

Comment: Yes, I did post it as an issue on GitHub. However the author has a page on the Wiki called [Rules of Conduct][1] there which says that questions about supporting a particular feature should be posted to Stackoverflow or Google Groups. My issue is half bug and half support-request so that's why I've cross posted. Up to now I haven't had any response so I'm waiting to see which post get a response. If that's the issue on GitHub then I'll happily delete the question in Stackoverflow.


[1]: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Rules-of-conduct